# In Parse.com cloud code, How to sort records by its child table

Tags: sorting, parse-platform

This question is about sorting by Pointer object in Parse.com cloud code.

I have an Class A object, and A.pointer is a Pointer object which point to Class B.

And I want to sort A in database by B.sortfield.

I've tried to use innerQuery like below, but seems not work.

```
        var query = new Parse.Query(A);
        var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(B);
        innerQuery.descending('sortfield');
        query.matchesQuery("pointer", innerQuery);
        query.......
```

Could anybody tell me how to do it? tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found below answers, Parse does not support such query. It really disappointed me.

[sort-a-query-based-on-a-data-in-another-table](https://parse.com/questions/sort-a-query-based-on-a-data-in-another-table)
and
[rest-api-sorting-query-through-a-pointer](https://parse.com/questions/rest-api-sorting-query-through-a-pointer)

Comment: The querying options in Parse are very very limited when working with more than one object :(